# Issues with badge icon

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange issue with badges.

Here is the code which sets badge count getted from backend

> UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge

so the issue is, when app connected to debugger its successfully changes the badge, but when I disable it from debugger and run it, the badge icon doesnt change, and its only on one iphone, other ones work fine with same code.

So can you help to understand the problem with this one?

Comment: iOS version of the affected device?

Comment: ios 11.2.5, but it works for other phone with same version

Comment: and also its doesnt change when I am in app,when my app is in background or killed,after push it changes

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with the device and not your app, have you tried restarting it?

Comment: I'll try it,but I think maybe I need to set it like this
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.badge = 10

Comment: but it strange that this code
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge
works for other phones with ios 11

Comment: Yeah exactly, that code should just work and the fact that it works while debugging then doesn't is very strange and doesn't really make sense at all.

Comment: agree,ok thanks will think that this is bug with phone )